# Formulating many constraints for optimization with python/gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am quite new at Python and Gurobi. I would appreciate if someone can help me with the constraints of an optimization.

I have a table that describes all the employees in a company, their location and their roles.

A small version of the table look like this:
[image]

As you can see if the employee has many skills it is repeated in the next row. This is because I need to create dummies to have 1's and 0's for each employee depending on the skills they have so I can selected them independently later on in the optimization. I have also created dummies with 1's and 0's for the locations. Finally I have done some coding and created dictionaries for all the variables, where if I call employeeLondon it will give me all the employees from London with a 1 and the rest will be 0. If I call employeeAR it will give me all the employees that have the role AR with 1s, and the rest of the employees 0's

The objective and decision variables are as follow:

```
m.setObjective(sum([1]), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

empls = {}
for e in lstempls:
  empls[e] = m.addVar(name = e ,vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

#lstempls is a list with all the employees in the company.

Examples of my constraints are:

```
m.addConstr ( sum ([empls[e] * employeeLondon[e] * employeeAR[e] for e in  empls.keys()] )  == 1 , "c London AR")

m.addConstr ( sum ([empls[e] * employeeLondon[e] * employeeUL[e] for e in  empls.keys()] )  == 1 , "c London UL" )

m.addConstr ( sum ([empls[e] * employeeBerlin[e] * employeeUL[e] for e in  empls.keys()] )  == 2 , "c Berlin UL" )
```

If I run the first constraint only it will give me a feasible result. However, with the last two constraints, as you can see I do not have and employee with the role UL in London and in Berlin I have only one, when I need two.

So, my question would be, there is any way I can add in the same constraint that if the role is no located at the indicated location just pick up another employee from a different location that has the required role, and if there is nobody with that role in any of the locations just pick up any other employee without considering the roles.

I said in the same constraint but if there is a better option without having to write the same code in each constraint, even better as this is a small version and I have many constrains.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restructure your approach to this from the ground up.

You are painting yourself into a corner with your current variable definition and by creating "dummies".  Duplicates in most LP applications are seldom needed (Aliases variables are another story.)

I don't use Gurobi, but the approach is similar in most any framework.

On your variable `e`...  What does it indicate?  I'm guessing that you want to indicate if some employee is assigned to work at some site in some role.  Right now that is impossible as there is no information contained in your variable as to which site or role the employee is assigned to.

I would also ditch `pandas` right away.  It isn't very helpful in most LP setups, and can lead to confusion if you aren't a real proficient `pandas` user.

So, how to structure this?  ...

You have 3 sets that are fundamental to your problem.  Declare them, or distill them out of your data frame:

```
Employees = [1122, 3315, 1234, ...]
Locations = ['London', 'Germany', ...]
Roles = ['AL', 'UR', ...]
```

Then (I'm guessing) your primary variable is going to be to `assign`, and it sounds like any employee can be assigned to any role in any spot, so:

```
assign[employee, location, role] ∈ Binary
```

Then you can keep preferences for location or role in dictionaries to make your constraints, etc.

And you can make constraints for location fills by doing something like:

```
for location in Locations:
    sum(assign[employee, location, role] for employee in Employees for role in Roles) >= requirement[location]
```

Set aside your goal of allowing employees to float all over the place for a bit and get that working.  You will need constraints to prevent employees from being assigned to multiple sites/roles as needed.

Then there are several ways to get preferred assignments, you can "score" them with points and maximize points in the OBJ function or such